# C# Convert IPv6 to ASN string

Tags: c#, ipv6, data-conversion

I am trying to convert IPv6 to ASN. I have been able to get two 64 bit pieces but I don't know how to put it together to get a single ASN as a string so that I may look it up in the database.

The code so far:

```
byte[] addrBytes = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ipv6Address).GetAddressBytes();
if (System.BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    //little-endian machines store multi-byte integers with the
    //least significant byte first. this is a problem, as integer
    //values are sent over the network in big-endian mode. reversing
    //the order of the bytes is a quick way to get the BitConverter
    //methods to convert the byte arrays in big-endian mode.
    System.Collections.Generic.List<byte> byteList = new   System.Collections.Generic.List<byte>(addrBytes);
    byteList.Reverse();
    addrBytes = byteList.ToArray();
}
ulong addrWords1, addrWords2;
if (addrBytes.Length > 8)
{
    addrWords1 = System.BitConverter.ToUInt64(addrBytes, 8);
    addrWords2 = System.BitConverter.ToUInt64(addrBytes, 0);
}
else
{
    addrWords1 = 0;
    addrWords2 = System.BitConverter.ToUInt32(addrBytes, 0);
}
```

Can you please help put addrWords1 and addrWords2 together into a string which represents the ASN?

E.g. 2001:200:: should return ASN 42540528726795050063891204319802818560

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "ASN"? That is certainly not a valid example of an [autonomous system number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_System_%28Internet%29).